# I want to search strings that starts with a pattern using C#

Tags: c#

I want to search string that start by another string.
Example:

```
<br>
{<br>
Sujith,<br>
surjith,<br>
rejith,<br>
}</p><br>
```

If the search word is 'su',should :

```
return<br>
{<br>
Sujith,<br>
surjith,<br>
}</p><br>
but not rejith
</p>
```

Comment: `str.ToLower().StartsWith("su")` returns a _boolean_.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class and build up yourself a [regular expression](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet) which does that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the StartsWith instance method on your string:

```
string searchString = "su";

List<string> result = nameList
                       .Where(x => x.StartsWith(searchString, true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
                       .ToList();
```